# How to create an additional column with the percentages related to a count distinct statement

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to query each distinct medical speciality (e.g. oncologist, pediatrician, etc.) in a table and then count the number of times a claim (`claim_id`) is linked to it, which I've done using this:

```
select distinct specialization, count(distinct claim_id) AS Claim_Totals
from table1
group by specialization
order by Claim_Totals DESC
```

However, I also want to include an additional column which lists the % that each speciality makes up in the table (based on the number of `claim_id` related to it). So for instance, if there were 100 total claims and "cardiologist" had 25 `claim_id` records related to it, "oncologist" had 15, "general surgeon" had 10, and so forth, I want the output to look like this:

```
specialization | Claims_Totals | PERCENTAGE
___________________________________________
cardiologist       25               25%
oncologist         15               15%
general surgeon    10               10%
```

Comment: `distinct` before `specialization` in the select list is redundant, since already included in the group by list

Answer (score 1):

Could do this? I'm not familiar with Barbaros's syntax. If that works its more concise and better.

```
select specialization, count(distinct claim_id) AS Claim_Totals, count(distinct claim_id)/total_claims
from table1 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT claim_id)*1.0000 total_claims AS total_claims 
               FROM table1 ) TMP
   ON 1 = 1
group by specialization
order by Claim_Totals DESC


select specialization, 
       count(distinct claim_id) AS claim_by_spec,
       count(distinct claim_id)/
       ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT claim_id)*1.0000
               FROM table1 ) AS percentage_calc
from table1 
group by specialization
order by Claim_Totals DESC
```

Comment: I keep getting a parsing error when I try to run this

Comment: @David I guess hive doesn't have "CROSS JOIN". Added some alternatives.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I think this works but I get the `percentage_calc` in a pretty undesirable format (e.g. 6.434891e-8, 0.00001241463087, etc.). The database is quite large so is there a way to make this look presentable? Thanks again

Comment: Are you sure you are multiplying by 1.0000 and not 10000?

Comment: I was just covering the possibility that hive does integer division

Comment: Yes I used 1.0000 and I think your query works correctly, I just wanted to clean it up a bit and round to the nearest thousandth or whatever so I don't have a bunch of super small numbers (which will be the case in some instances)

Comment: Rounding to the thousandth would be round(whatever_value_you_want, 3);

Comment: where would I put round() in that query? I tried a few different things and couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum(count(distinct)) over()` to get the overall claims and use it in the denominator to get the percentage.

```
select specialization
      ,count(distinct claim_id) AS Claim_Totals
      ,round(100*count(distinct claim_id)/sum(count(distinct claim_id)) over(),3) as percentage
from table1
group by specialization
```

Comment: thanks for posting, I believe this works correctly, but the format of the `percentage` column is pretty messy. Is there a way to clean it up to include something like just 10.115% (or round to the nearest thousandth)?

Comment: use the function `round` on the result with the required number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: could you show me how to build this into your specific query? I'm not familiar with round function

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`,concat_ws('',count(distinct claim_id),'%') as percentage`

or

`,concat(count(distinct claim_id),'%') as percentage`

as added to the select list's tail

Btw, `distinct` before specialization in the select list is redundant, since already included in the group by list.

Comment: I tried running both but they just gave me the Claim_Totals column as a %. I wanted to make the percentage in the new column proportional to the sum of the total claims. Sorry that wasn't super clear in my original comment.

Comment: @David did you add to you select list as `select specialization, count(distinct claim_id) AS Claim_Totals, concat(count(distinct claim_id),'%') as percentage`

Comment: I used:

```select specialization, count(distinct claim_id) AS Claim_Totals, concat(count(distinct claim_id),'%') as percentage
from table1
group by specialization
order by Claim_Totals DESC```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `count(distinct)`, window functions are less useful.  You can try:

```
select t1.specialization,
       count(distinct t1.claim_id) AS Claim_Totals,
       count(distinct t1.claim_id) / tt1.num_claims
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select count(distinct claim_id) as num_claims
      from table1
     ) tt1
group by t1.specialization
order by Claim_Totals DESC
```